# Boas práticas para se criar um projeto em Angular

Tags: angular

Estou estudando Angular para desenvolver uma aplicação web, e gostaria de saber quais as boas práticas quanto a criação de pastas, criação das classes referente ao service e demais partes.

Fiz uma busca no Google mas não encontrei nada semelhante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A melhor pratica para gerar um projeto angular de acordo com a [documentação](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) e com o [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).

Para instalar o angular cli globalmente

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Depois para gerar o projeto:

```
ng new NOME_DO_PROJETO
```

Para gerar um componente por exemplo

```
ng generate component meu-component
```

Também pode se usar somente g para ficar mais curto veja o exemplo de como gerar um serviço:

```
ng g service meu-service
```

Todas as opções possíveis do generate assim como suas flags estão disponíveis [aqui](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate)

**EDIT**

Sobre a arquitetura de projetos angular:

A [documentação oficial](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#application-structure-and-ngmodules) sugere uma  arquitetura por features.
 Pois imagine que você coloque todos os services juntos ou todos componentes juntos separados de seus respectivos html. Essa arquitetura e desencorajada desde o angularJS pois não escala bem. Imagina se você tem 50 components tem que achar ele no meio de 50 dentro de uma pasta components não e uma boa.
conforme sua aplicação for crescendo vai ficar super difícil achar o component que você quer. Por isso ter uma arquitetura por rotas/feature e bem mais fácil de você achar os components e arquivos que você quer em aplicacoes grandes.

Outra vantagem de fazer a arquitetura por features e que você pode fazer um [lazy-loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) dos seus módulos somente quando eles forem necessários. Fazendo uma aplicação grande muito mais rápida. Imagina que você tem uma rota /admin pode ser que 80% dos seus usuários nunca acessem aquela rota e pode ser que ela contenha components bem pesados que deixariam seu site devagar pra carregar. Por isso faz todo sentido carregar ela somente quando aquela rota for acessado deixando seu site bem mais leve.

Sendo assim deve ser mais especificamente uma arquitetura por rotas. E consequentemente por features.

Neste caso se vc tiver por exemplo uma rota /usuarios que lista usuários.

voce teria uma pasta

usuario

- usuario.module.ts
- usuario.routing.module.ts
- usuario.container.component.ts
- usuario.container.component.scss
- usuario.container.component.html
- usuario.interface.ts --> este seria   o equivalente ao model.
- usuario.service.ts

usuario-list dentro desta pasta usuario

- usuario.list.component.ts
- usuario.list.component.scss
- usuario.list.component.html

Comment: Eu referi na minha pergunta mais especificamente onde direcionar os arquivos como por exemplo, do service, do model e por aí vai...

Comment: Editei a resposta sobre a arquitetura do projeto

Comment: Interessante, eu desenvolvo em Java e colocava tudo separado sabe, conforme aprendi na empresa, os services tudo junto e por aí vai. Engraçado q em um vídeo vi q devíamos criar uma pasta chamada `shared` e colocar por exemplo os models dentro dela

Comment: O que me preocupa além da organização é também nas aulas e livros, não é mencionado questão de herança ao criar classes de serviço por exemplo

Comment: E discutível isso de colocar os models dentro de uma pasta shard/models eu so colocaria as interfaces que são compartilhadas de fato e não todas. No mundo web se recomenda usar composição invés de herança.

Comment: Só sobre a parte de herança, seria mais direcionado as classes do service, criando métodos abstratos de crud

Comment: Somente uma referência boa `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346342/which-type-of-folder-structure-should-be-used-with-angular-2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa`